# how do I set up K Version Manager (KVM) properly so I can run KVM anywhere in powershell later?

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I  set up K Version Manager (KVM) properly so I can run KVM by typing "KVM" anywhere in powershell later? Do I have to add pathing to the HOME repo?

Answer (score 3):

Run `kvm use` and pass the `-p` (persistent) argument. This will add `kvm` to the user's path or to the system path, if combined with `-g`.

If you run  `kvm help` you will get all the available arguments:

```
kvm use <semver>|<alias>|none [-x86][-x64] [-svr50][-svrc50] [-p|-persistent] [-g|-global]
  <semver>|<alias>  add KRE bin to path of current command line
  none              remove KRE bin from path of current command line 
  -p|-persistent    add KRE bin to PATH environment variables persistently
  -g|-global        combined with -p to change machine PATH instead of user PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [Getting Started section at aspnet\Home](https://github.com/aspnet/Home#getting-started).

Once you execute the `kvmsetup.cmd` it will add `kvm` to the path for all future powershell\command line sessions.